# Why jersey is showing on my Spring boot MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, jersey

I have my server running on tomcat 8, I use the Spring Boot framework without any of the Jersey components, but still from some reason, I get this Log data when I start my server:

**INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@310ddd95, com.server.ServletInitializer@43b26169]**

NOTE: my server run just fine, but I didn't use any Jersey, so WHY do i get this Info?

this is my main configuration class:

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:/META-INF/application-context.xml"})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication {...}
```

This is another conf class:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class CustomWebMvcAutoConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {...}
```

Another conf class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {}
```

And also this one **(which I think is the big problem)**:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration` is part of Spring Boot and contains autoconfiguration for Jersey (which is only active when Jersey is on the classpath). However, it also contains an inner class which implements the interface `WebApplicationInitializer`, and since Spring detects all implementations of that interface, you get this log message (as you can see, this appears just in a list of all implementations, which also contains your implementation of the `WebApplicationInitializer` interface).

However, maybe this is a bug, because in my opinion it shouldn't detect the WebApplicationInitializer, if the surrounding autoconfiguration is not active. In this case you should open a bug report in the Github project of Spring Boot (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues).

Comment: I must ask, how do u know that "the surrounding autoconfiguration is not active"?

Comment: You say, that you use Spring Boot "without any of the Jersey components". So i assume you don't have any Jersey related dependencies on the classpath. And then the autoconfiguration shouldn't be active. Of course, if you have Jersey on your classpath, it works as it should and you should probably clean up your dependencies.

Comment: well I don't have any dependency in my classpath and I do not use any Jersey (even cleaned my unused import just in case), so basically I will go for a bug report... :)

Comment: I opened a bug on github project of spring boot, they confirmed. here is a link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5778